# Generate sphinx documentation with Django tags

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx

I am trying to generate a sphinx documentation using the Read the Docs template for a Django project.
I am documenting it using the Django tags

For example `` Download :model:`ManagementSoftware.Order` CSV ``

When I try to generate the documentation with the command `make html` I get the error

```
docstring of ManagementSoftware.views.DownloadOrdersCSV:1: ERROR: Unknown interpreted text role "model".
```

What should I do? Is there any sphinx extension to include those tags?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is `ManagementSoftware.Order`? Is it a class or method whose docstring you want to render? Something else? Do you just want to generate a link to download a CSV file that is included with your documentation?

Comment: I think `:model:` is a custom cross-reference role. It must obviously be defined somewhere, but I don't know anything about it.